# how to add extra singup field in accounts

Tags: meteor

I'd like to add a fiew more fields to my splendido default signup template,
here's my configuration:

```
 AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp', {layoutTemplate: 'generalLayout'});
```

Comment: Ooookay so did you already try anything? Also you have a couple typos.

Comment: i get the default signup template , i need to add more fields to it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var pwd = AccountsTemplates.removeField('password');
AccountsTemplates.removeField('email');
AccountsTemplates.addFields([
  {
      _id: "newfield",
      type: "text",
      displayName: "Field Name",
      required: true,
      minLength: 5,
  },
  {
      _id: "username",
      type: "text",
      displayName: "username",
      required: true,
      minLength: 5,
  },
  pwd
]);
```

inside /lib folder or anywhere reachable from client and server